# Number theory: solution need

Tags: algorithm, twos-complement, number-theory, digital-logic

Suppose `a = a31 a30 . . . a1 a0` is a 32-bit binary word.
Consider the 32-bit binary word `b = b31 b30 . . . b1 b0` computed by the following algorithm:

1. Scan a from right to left and copy its bits to `b` until the first `1` is found (which is also copied to `b`)
2. After that, copy the Boolean negations of the bits in `a`.

For example, `a = 10100 . . . 00` is transformed to `b = 01100 . . . 00`. Explain what this algorithm computes if `a` and `b` are interpreted as binary numbers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a homework dump.

Answer (score 1):

It's for 2's complement computation.

You could see that `b` indeed equals to `~a+1`, which means `b` is `a`'s 2's complement.

Answer (score 0):

It's two's complement, as timrau noted. The answer is easy to find if you already know it (as I did), but harder to derive.

Start with the part that is copied:

```
copy_mask = a ^ (a - 1)    // extract rightmost 1 and smear to the right
```

Obviously, the part that isn't copied (and thus "negated", as you called it) is simply the complement of that mask:

```
negated_mask = ~copy_mask
```

And now we can build `b`:

```
b = (a & copy_mask) | (~a & ~copy_mask)
```

Substitute:

```
b = (a & (a ^ (a - 1))) | (~a & ~(a ^ (a - 1)))
```

Simplify:

```
// move complement into xor
b = (a & (a ^ (a - 1))) | (~a & (a ^ ~(a - 1)))
// use two's complement definition
b = (a & (a ^ (a - 1))) | (~a & (a ^ -a))
// use two's complement definition
b = (a & ~(a ^ -a)) | (~a & (a ^ -a))
// use definition of xor: p^q = (p&~q)|(~p&q)
b = a ^ (a ^ -a)
// use xor associativity
b = (a ^ a) ^ -a
// simplify xor with self
b = -a
```

There's probably a shorter way that doesn't skip too many steps..

Comment: thanks timrau and harold